How to use custom prices in Paddle gateway?
I'm trying to use Paddle payment gateway: https://developer.paddle.com/
But i could not figure out how to set a custom price. All prices need to be configured through Paddle's dashboard and recalled by theire IDs. Which is not useful in my use case.
Is there any approach i can follow to use my own custom prices?
